# How to prevent inserting same Name and NricNo data in a table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Table

```
ID   | Name | NricNo
1    | Joshua | S1234567A
2    | Joshua | S1234567A
```

I have a problem for this table. ID is the primary key of this table, but I need to make Name,NricNo to be unique too. It means that table cannot have duplicate value of Name and NricNo. I am doing this in visual studio 2010, help needed . Thanks :)

Comment: Just add a unique constrain on the combination of fields.

Comment: What is the syntax for that? Thanks.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx

Comment: Does this work in sql server 2008?

Comment: It should. If you want to be absolutely certain, there is a selector at the top of msdn pages to select the version of either SQL Server or Visual Studio. Here is the link for the 2008 version: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can simply alter your table with this query.

ALTER TABLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT  UNIQUE ();
GO

--Example :
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT AK_MyTable UNIQUE (Name, NricNo);
GO

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on how you're doing your database interactions. If you're using Entity Framework, as long as you're not creating a new object with the same values, you should be fine.

Either way, you could help yourself by adding an ID field to your data object. If you're using ADO.NET, then check the ID in your save method. If it's not equal to a default value (you should default it to -1 to be safe), then Update, otherwise Insert. Have your saving in a try/catch block because with the UNIQUE constraint on the table, if you try to insert a record that conflicts with the UNIQUE key, then it will throw an error. If you use Entity Framework, most of that would be handled for you, but you should still have the try/catch in your save method.